# EF6 LINQ cast column

Tags: linq, entity-framework, casting

My entity has a field called `Value`. This field is a `string`, but it hold `int` and `DateTime` values also.

My regular query is something like

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE entityType=@eID and CAST(value as int/datetime/varchar)==@value
```

How can I make **EF** generate a query with a cast?

Edit: create suggestion on [uservoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6983885-convert-toint)

Comment: Can you say how you should cast value based on `entityType`?

Comment: @teovankot entityType is another field that tells me if I should cast to int, datetime or varchar... ID=1 means int, 2 means datetime and 0 string...

Comment: You should absolutely do this the other way around: cast `@value` to the required type. Applying functions to database fields before comparing them impairs indexes.

Comment: What's the point of a DateTimeOffset field then if you cannot cast it to datetime before comparing it against a local date?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was implemented and completed by the EF team. Check the user invoice link listed on the question

Answer (score -1):

Here is example:

```
        int eId = 1;
        int valueInt = 1;
        DateTime valueDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string valueString = "Test";

        TableA result;
        switch (eId)
        {
            case 1: result = context.tableA.Where(x => x.entityType == eId && Convert.ToInt32(x.value) == valueInt); break;
            case 2: result = context.tableA.Where(x => x.entityType == eId && Convert.ToDateTime(x.value) == valueDateTime); break;
            case 3: result = context.tableA.Where(x => x.entityType == eId && x.value == valueString); break;
        }
```

Comment: did you even test that before posting it as answer?

Comment: No, but linq can translate convert functions to sql right way

Comment: really? can you point any kind of source that backs that claim? i`ve been looking for a long time... no luck so far...

Comment: Here is [msdn list of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882655.aspx) that linq to sql doesn't support. `toInt32` and `toDateTime` not listed there so i belive they should work :) but be carefull with to date time i beliave that convertion can be influed by current `collation` on sql server, but you always can see what's happened in profiler :)

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 is definitely not supported.

Comment: @teo-van-kot - I just tried it my end and I didn't work.

Comment: @RobertoBonini you make a mistake somewhere here is [msdn list of what Convert Function DOES NOT SUPPORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882655(v=vs.110).aspx) all others functions have SQL translation and working.